# Font(Text) not resizing with respect to the width change

Tags: html, css

In the below two images, you can see that **changing the width** does not have any impact on **font size** and thus the **text is coming out of the **sidebar**.

I want the **siderbar text** to **resize itself** as the width of its **parent (sidebar) decreases** with *respect to the body*

Codes **(HTML and CSS)** are given below the images

[image]

[image]

**HTML:-**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
                    <div class="header-image"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="left-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="right-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">+91 964941****</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="content-a">
            <span>DEMO SESSIONS</span>
            <h1>Get Demo Class Now</h1>
            <p>We offer demo sessions before making you enroll in any training course. 
               We respect your money and our content quality will be worth every penny of yours. Have Faith :) </p>
        </div>

        <aside class="siderbar">
            <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Discord</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:-

```
body{
    background-color:#191C26;
    color:white;
}
/* Start of Header */
.header{
    margin-top:20px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:150px;
}
.header-image{
    width:10%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:36px;
}

.header-image img{
    width:100%;
}

.left-menu, .right-menu{

    list-style: none;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.left-menu a, .right-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color:white;
}

.left-menu{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:12%;
}

.left-menu li{
    float:left;
  
}

.left-menu a{
  margin-right:20px;
}
.right-menu{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}

.right-menu li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.right-menu a{
    margin-left:20px;
}

/*End of Header */

/*Start of Mid Content*/
.content-a{
   width:45%;
   margin:auto;
   margin-top:80px;
}

.content-a h1{
    font-size: 150px;
    margin:0px;
}

.siderbar{
    display:inline-block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:800px;
    width:10%;
    background-color: black;;

}
.siderbar ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:400px;
    margin-bottom:486px;
    width:100%;
    
}

.siderbar a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:inherit;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this maybe will work, try this (use media query for responsive)

CSS:

```
.siderbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
 }

@media (min-width: 55rem) {
  .siderbar a {
    font-size: 1rem;
   }
 }

@media (max-width: 55rem) {
  .siderbar a {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 42rem) {
  .siderbar a {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using pixel value use **rem** or **em**.

Eg: You wrote something like this

```
.content-a h1{
    font-size: 150px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Use this instead

```
.content-a h1{
   font-size: 9.375rem;
   margin:0;
 }
```

**Note:** em and rem are relative length while pixel (px) is an absolute length value

Answer (score 1):

try using vw for font size like this:

```
font-size: 8vw;
```

or use media queries like this :

```
/* If the screen size is 601px wide or more, set the font-size of <div> to 80px */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

/* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```